# How to unpack only some arguments from zip, not all?

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

My SQL query:

```sql
select id,value,zvalue from axis
```

gives me result like this:

```
ans=(1,23,34)(12,34,35)(31,67,45)(231,3412,234)
```

now if I want all these 3 variables as 3 different lists

```py
id, value, zvalue = zip(*ans)
```

But if I only want `id` and `value` as separate lists. It will give me **too many values to unpack error**.

```py
id, value = zip(*ans)
```

Is there any way where I can create any number of lists from SQL query. Because if there are 10 parameters in the query, I have to use all the parameters while using ZIP?

Comment: You have to use a "placeholder variable" for that. `id, value, _ = ...`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The number of arguments must match, this is a rule in Python 2. For Python 3, you can use * to capture into a list.

The common pythonic (2.x) workaround is to use `_` to denote variables you won't use, i.e.:

```
id,value,_ = zip(*ans) # only works for exactly three values
```

As DSM commented, for Python 3, you can use * to grab "remaining" args as a list:

```
id, value, *_ = zip(*ans) # _ will be a list of zero or more args
```

Or, simplest, just slice the return from zip:

```
id,value = zip(*ans)[:2] # ignore all but first two values
```

Comment: The rule that the number of arguments must match is relaxed a bit in Python 3, where something like "first, *middle, last = [1,2,3,4]" gives you 1, [2,3], 4.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Python 3 you can use this for unpacking *n* additional elements:

```
In [0]: a, b, *_ = (1, 2, 3, 4)

In [1]: a
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
ids = [t[0] for t in ans]
values = [t[1] for t in ans]
```

The first list comprehension gets the first column in all tuples in `ans`, that is, the `id` column. The second list comprehension gets the second column for all tuples in `ans`, that is,  the `value` column.